# Dependency Injection calls in Libraries .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

What is the correct way for a Libary to call an object that was injected through Dependency Inject?

Background: I have multiple .NET Core app that uses dependency injection for all major objects and uses libraries for reusability.  It is working great.  App1 calls Libary1 and Libary2. App2 calls Libary2 and Libary3 etc.

```
service.AddTransient<Libary1.ILibary1Dependency, Libary1.Libary1Dependency>();
service.AddTransient<Libary2.ILibary1Dependency, Libary2.Libary1Dependency>();
service.AddTransient<Libary2.ILibary2Dependency, Libary2.Libary2Dependency>();
service.AddTransient<Libary3.ILibary1Dependency, Libary3.Libary1Dependency>();
```

Now in `Libary2.ILibary1Dependency` there is a method that needs to call a new `Libary2.ILibary2Dependency`.  What is the best way to do this?

Should I just do a `new Libary2.ILibary2Dependency(property1, property2...);`?

Is it ok in the main app to actually inject the `IServiceCollection` object and then in the constructor of the `Libary2.ILibary1Dependency` get the `IServiceCollection`?

Is there some nugget package that I don't know about that fixes this perfectly?

Note: `Libary2.ILibary2Dependency` does get called on its own via dependency injection, if you were wondering

Comment: Correct for a library is (arguably) to not assume the caller is using any kind of dependency injection framework at all, lest you tie them to your specific framework. If an `ILibrary2Dependency` object is needed, inject it at the call site: either the constructor of an object, or the method being called, or (if the class really needs to construct instances independently) inject a `Func<ILibrary2Dependency>`. While you *can* pass around `IServiceCollection`s, by doing so you reintroduce exactly the problem DI was intended to solve: that dependencies should be explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, keep the libraries independent of the Service Dependency Injection. And let the Caller make the decision to inject them on need basis and it helps to keep the libraries independent of IOC Framework.

If you need to change the IOC Framework or even upgrade to latest versions, you probably need to spend time to update across the libraries, the more these dependencies you have the more house cleaning needed eventually.

I have seen people creating  generic wrappers to avoid having specific dependencies on IOC Frameworks, but its kind of overkill.

If all you have is a 3 or 4 projects, it doesn't matter to refactor them away in both directions.